# Saving/copy back configurations from Apache, Mysql? Because I want to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, mysql, configure

On my server I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. Bind9, Apache, MySql etc worked fine, until a few month ago I got some problems with mailman. I don't know what happened, but I can't install, remove or reinstall mailman. And because the mailman-update isn't installed, it keeps coming back and is prefenting me from updating other software (e.g. Bind9, Mysql, etc) when available. :(

Now, I want to install Ubuntu 14.04-server from scratch. But this means I have to configure all the server software. Unless there has to be a way that the configurations that are made in Bind9, Apache, Mysql, etc can be copied to e.g. an external USB-harddrive, and later, can be copied back to the fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04-server harddrive.

If this is possible, which files (and/or folders) do I have to copy to external harddrive for:

- Apache
- Bind9
- Mysql
- Postfix

I would be great if this is possible. It would save me a lot of time. ;)

Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I've been working along the same lines.  I have made this list of files & directories that I rsync to my backup.  At some point I have edited or done something to each of these.  Configurations will vary (for example, I use nullmailer instead of postfix, and I don't have mysql), but perhaps this will be a starting point for you.

```
/etc/apache2 
/etc/sysctl.conf 
/etc/fstab 
/etc/bind 
/etc/host.conf 
/etc/modsecurity 
/etc/fail2ban 
/etc/psad 
/etc/ufw
/etc/ddclient.conf 
/etc/default/ddclient 
/etc/default/bind9
/etc/ssh 
/etc/rkhunter.conf 
/etc/openvpn 
/etc/hosts
/etc/nullmailer
/etc/mailname
/etc/samba
/etc/rsyslog.d/20-ufw.conf
/etc/sudoers.d/sudoers
/etc/tripwire
/etc/pwrstatd.conf
/etc/pwrstatd-email.sh
/etc/pwrstatd-lowbatt.sh
/etc/pwrstatd-powerfail.sh
/lib/ufw 
/usr/share/modsecurity-crs 
/usr/share/GeoIP
/usr/share/logwatch  
/var/www
```

Answer (score 1):

During an upgrade the mailman troubles started ?
Can you try : sudo dpkg -P mailman

If that doesn't work, do : sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mailman*

(If that gives troubles : sudo apt-get -f install)
and then try : sudo dpkg -P mailman
to purge mailman package.

Regarding backups, if you rsync /etc/ /var/lib/ /var/www/ then things should be fine in general.

In Debian/Ubuntu based server installs /etc/ is where all config files live, and in /var/lib/ there's e.g. mysql, LDAP, samba directories which have some importance.
For mysql it is actually recommended to use mysqldumps as well, especially if you use innoDB format.

On servers I always like to install automysqlbackup package.

```
sudo apt-get install automysqlbackup
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=automysqlbackup

It is really easy and convenient to have.

You can install it, and it will then use a cronjob to put nightly backups in /var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily/ but you can run the command "automysqlbackup" right away with sudo right to produce that mysqldump on the fly, ready to be copied to your backup location.

Comment: I tried the commands, but I didn't work. When I do 'sudo dpkg -P mailman' I get: package is in poor and inconsistent condition; you have to install it again, before you can try to remove it. When I do 'sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mailman*' it hangs at that: 'Looking for languages'-point (this may take some time)..done'. Even waiting hours it won't go on. When I do 'sudo apt-get -f install' the install hangs again at: 'Looking for enabled languages (this may take some time)... done'. When  I want install automysqlbackup it will first install mailman first. :(

Comment: Can you give me the complete command syntax for the rsync, please. Thanks.

Comment: Note : For rsync to work you need to have rsync installed on the local and remote computer. I assume that rsync comes default on Ubuntu installs (desktop and server install). Here is an example : rsync -av "-e ssh" --numeric-ids your-remote-username@your-remote-hostname:/etc/ ./etc-backup/  With rsync it is important to mind the / characters at the end of pathnames.  Another option is to use secure copy (openssh) : scp -rpv your-remote-username@your-remote-hostname:/etc/ ./etc-backup-scp/  See also here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Comment: That sounds like a "stubborn" mailman package problem :(  Can you try the sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mailman* again, and when it seems to hang, press control c, and see whether it would continue the install

Comment: I have done the command: sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/mailman* . It did hang again at the same point mentioned earlier. After pressing Ctrl C I get the message: dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mailman_1%3a2.1.16-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb (--install): subprocess new pre-installation script was interrupted. Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/mailman_1%3a2.1.16-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb

Comment: Today do I tried again the command you gave me earlier: 'sudo dpkg -P mailman'. This time I did get the message: "dpkg: warning: files list for package 'mailman' is missing; it is assumed that the packet has no installed files. (Read database .. 121922 files and directories currently installed.); mailman (1: 2.1.16-2ubuntu0.1) is removed ... Configuration files for mailman (1: 2.1.16-2ubuntu0.1) are deleted".  So, the mailman-problem has been solved and I could install/update all the other packages again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kevinx Nice to hear you got it working now !